# Moving controls on screen when scroll view is affected

Tags: ios, uibutton, scrollview, move, fixed

I am developing an app. I have a screen with approximately 15 controls on it.Buttons,UITextfields,Mapkit and UITextviews. The textviews are at the bottom of the screen. so when i click to enter a value i have a scroll view that shifts the controls up like i wanted.Now i have 5 controls (custom buttons), that i have placed on the screen at a particular x,y locations.They are stuck to the screen. When i enter the textview all controls move up but these don't , because they are given their special x,y locations. I want to make them move as well. How do i do it? I was thinking do some math and when every control moves these also move by a certain "delta". Or is there any easy way for scroll view to tell that pick these "fixed buttons" and move them up like any other control. Do i make sense?If you need more information please ask.Thanks..

[image]

This picture shows what i am trying to do. So there are 4 UIbuttons that are attached to the screen. I make them fixed to the screen by making a CGRect like this

```
CGRectMake(20, 72, 180, 43)
CGRectMake(200, 72, 180, 43)
CGRectMake(380, 72, 180, 43)

CGRectMake(90, 380, 180, 43)
```

The rectangles in bold are the ones that i made by fixing them to those co-ordinates. So i click on the second Uitextview and a delegate gets fired and moves up all the controls. That include the 3 rectangles (NOT BOLD ONES) and first uitextivew to shift up.I do that because the keyboard was hiding second uitextview while i was entering data into it. But now the UIBUTTONS (BOLDED Rectangles) stay put on the screen. When i hide the keypad the app screen is normal. How do i make the bolded rectangles also move up with the not bolded rectangles.

```
    ITMToggleButtonView *aOnToggleButton = [[ITMToggleButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(495, 21, 80, 43)
                                                                           andIndex:3
                                                                           andTitle:@"Add On?"
                                                                           andState:NO];
aOnToggleButton.delegate = self;
```

...created the other 4 custom toggle buttons

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:stToggleButton];
[self.scrollView addSubview:rdToggleButton];
[self.scrollView addSubview:ecToggleButton];
[self.scrollView addSubview:aOnToggleButton];
[self.scrollView addSubview:sCToggleButton];
```

EDIT: Solution.I added my custom created toggleButtons(BOLDED rectangles) like you see here and added them to my scrollView. So when keyboard shows up the scrollview moves up and so do all my controls (Bolded and Not bolded ones). It was a simple fix.

Comment: @Rob. I added a link to the mockup and also gave explanation of the scenario. Please take a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to address this is to ensure that all controls that scroll together should be all be subviews of the same subview (in your case, it sounds like a `UIScrollView`). So if the non-bold controls, which are moving when the keyboard shows up, are on a `UIScrollView`, then you should put the bold ones on the same subview, e.g. the same `UIScrollView` as the other controls.

I assume there's some reason, though, that you've added some controls to the `UIScrollView` (maybe you're adding them programmatically) and others are not (maybe you added them via Interface Builder). You need to explain your logic for why are subviews of the scroll view and others aren't. As always, sharing meaningful snippets of code will help. It's almost impossible to diagnose these sorts of issues in the abstract.

Bottom line, it sounds like the issue is not the `CGRect` coordinates you used for adding the bold controls, but rather to which view you added them as a subview. We could try to walk through the synchronizing of the animating the changing coordinates for the various "non-moving" controls with the scrollview, but that's going to be a little clumsy and it's better to just get them all on the same subview.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. All the controls are subviews of scrollview, except the bolded ones. I am creating them programmatically and they are supposed to be at that precise location. Remaining controls i added them from IB. I solved my issue. When keyboard is shown is hit, i get the bolded control while looping through subviews and make a new CGRect.And when keypad is hidden is hit then i loop them and move the control to original location.I will add edit to my question on how i did it.I will see if my colleagues will agree with this approach for the time being.Thanks again.